# delphi, windows impersonation as user to copy a file

Tags: windows, api, delphi, authentication, impersonation

I need to copy a file located on a directory on my newtwork to my local machine. I did some research and i found a function called Windows API, but when I tried to call copy file I received an access denied message. 
Here is the project.

```
procedure TForm1.btnLoginLogOnClick(Sender: TObject);
var
   phToken: THandle;
begin
   WriteLog('');
   WriteLog('Current user: ' + GetCurrentUser());
   // check for correct login
   phToken := 0;
   try
   phToken := CheckLogin(Edit1.Text, Edit2.Text, Edit3.Text); //user,password,domain
   WriteLog('Handle: ' + IntToStr(phToken));
   if (phToken > 0) Then begin
      WriteLog('User login ok');

      // login ok, switch ACL to new login context (demo purpose only)
      ImpersonateLoggedOnUser(phToken);

      WriteLog('Impersonated user: ' + GetCurrentUser());
     if( CopyFile(PWideChar(Edit4.Text),('C:\cp2101.zip'),false)=false) then//CopyFile('c:\a.jpg','c:\warn.jpg',true))=false then
            ShowMessage(SysErrorMessage(GetLastError));

      // revert back to original login context
      RevertToSelf;
      WriteLog('Reverted to original user: ' + GetCurrentUser());

      TQuery(phToken, Edit3.Text);
      TQueryGroups(phToken, Edit3.Text);

   end else begin
      WriteLog('User login failed');
   end;

   finally
      CloseHandle(phToken);
   end;
end;
```

this is the project: [Project link](https://mega.co.nz/#!45RnXa6D!eYsaVBHBAkpq6sK8-ARCyR5ev8QQO2PoeOGTNdP_UmY)

Comment: Why do you need to impersonate the user that's already running this app (and therefore shouldn't need to be impersonated at all)? You say you can do this using Windows Explorer and it works, which means there's no need for impersonation in the first place. Just use `CopyFile` without all of the other code.

Answer (score 1):

The first suggestion is that you do not have permissions to access the network directory, or the file in question. These could be access permissions or copy permissions (or both).
Check that you have permissions to both of these.

Comment: Ask that question on Meta, @Sherlock.

Comment: @Sherlock70 It's called suggested edits. You can do it too. Click on the edit, make your change. Then the edit goes into a review queue. Other users can only see the edit if high rep users review the edits and accept them.

Comment: i try the same operation myself by windows explorer and it worked well, and i don't understand what's the problem

Answer (score 0):

So, If Windows expolorer can copy this file, you can use SHFileOperation:

```
procedure SHCopyFile(const Source, Dest: string);
var
  OP: SHFILEOPSTRUCT;
begin
  With Op do
  begin
    WND := 0;
    wFunc := FO_COPY;
    pFrom := PChar(Source + #0#0);
    fFlags := 0;
    pTo := PChar(Dest + #0);
    fAnyOperationsAborted := False;
    hNameMappings := Nil;
    lpszProgressTitle := Nil;
  end;
  SHFileOperation(Op);

end;
```